# Error with MKMapView

Tags: objective-c, xcode, mkmapview, uisearchbar

When I create the story board below the map over takes the entire screen. This is understandble with the code that I have below it uses the entire bounds of the view. However, if I do a normal "init", I lose functionality of the map! The map usually zooms into my location, and a few other things.  When I use init instead of initWithFrame the map doesn't go to my location.

```
 self.myMapView =[[MKMapView alloc]initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];

 self.myMapView.delegate=self;
```

How do I initialize the map without having it take over the entire screen like shown in my story board.  New to iOS, thanks for your help!

[image: Capture of StoryBoard]

```
//Setting up the location manger for finding the User's location
self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc]init];
self.locationManager.delegate = self;

//Check to see if they have Authorization to use to use location servieces
if ([self.locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAlwaysAuthorization)])
{
    [self.locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
}

    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];


//Initialize the map and specifiy bounds
self.myMapView =[[MKMapView alloc]initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];

//Set the delegate to itself
self.myMapView.delegate=self;

//Set a standard mapview, Enable scrolling and zooming
self.myMapView.mapType = MKMapTypeStandard;
self.myMapView.scrollEnabled = YES;
self.myMapView.zoomEnabled = YES;
//specifcy resizing
self.myMapView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth |        UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin;

//show the User's location and set tracking mode
self.myMapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
self.myMapView.userTrackingMode = MKUserTrackingModeFollow;

//add the VIEW!!
[self.view addSubview:self.myMapView];

//Set up the UISearch Bar
self.mySearch = [[UISearchBar alloc]init];
self.mySearch.delegate  = self;

//Set the initial Text
self.mySearch.prompt = @"Enter Address or Use Current Location";
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Do you want to add the map view in the storyboard or create it in code? You shouldn't do both.

Comment: Forgive me I am new to iOS, I drop the MKMapView onto the view controller, and I believe created it in code in the viewDidLoad method. I have added the rest of my code.

Comment: Since you added it to your controller in the storyboard, you shouldn't also create one in code. Just size it how you want in the storyboard, and add the proper constraints to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's two approaches to create your map view.

1.Create in code. As shown in your example. You need to set the map view frame. If you need firstly to create UISearchBar, you should set map view frame according to search bar position. It might look like this.

```
self.mySearch = [[UISearchBar alloc] init];
self.mySearch.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 40);
//...
self.myMapView = [[MKMapView alloc] init];
self.myMapView.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.mySearch.frame.size.height, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height - self.mySearch.frame.size.height);
//...
```

2.Much more simpler way - create in storyboard. Firstly, there no need to create your outlets (such as search bar and map view) in code. You simple drag'n'drop all the controls to view. Open your storyboard, set the view controller class from UIViewController to your class name.

Note that the properties must be IBOutlets

```
@property (nonatomic,weak) IBOutlet MKMapView *myMapView;
@property (nonatomic,weak) IBOutlet UISearchBar *mySearchBar;
```

After dropping your controls to view, you must connect visual controls to your class outlets. Take a look at this [tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ios/ios_actions_and_outlets.htm) where connections are explained.